# What Laravel Cache is used for?

Tags: laravel, caching

I read the documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/cache) but didn't understand what cache is used for. Yesterday I got a problem, and the solution was clear the cache and didn't even know that it exist.

So my question is, what is Laravel cache and what is it used for.

Any explanation will be apreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The cache is used to store a result. Let's take a News item as an example. There is no need to get that from the database on every request, as it is not likely to change all the time. Getting it from the database can be slow and put load on the database. A cache is a way to store a result and quickly find it again based on a key.

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "title": "News Title",
  "body": "News Body..."
}
```

Could be stored using:

```
return Cache::remember('news-1', 1440, static function() {
   return News::whereKey(1)->first();
});
```

The code inside the closure (static function) will be remembered under key `news-1`, for 1440 minutes, so it can be extracted from the cache(fast) instead of the database(slower) on every request.

In case the news item does change, you can listen to that using events/observers. So if you updated/deleted is triggered, you can forget that key, so its removed from the cache.

```
Cache::forget('news-1');
```

There is much more to it, than what I have explained here, but this should give you a basic idea of what's going on.